# Why do we use SGD and not a root finding numerical method to compute the gradient equal to 0 for convex functions?

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let's suppose we have a convex function F(x), where $x\in\mathbb{R}^D$. Since F is convex, we know that the global minimum is found by solving the system of equations $\nabla F(x)=0$.

My question is, numerically, why don't we find the roots of $\nabla F(x)=0$ by means of a numerical method like Newton-Raphson instead of updating with SGD and variants, i.e.,

$x^{k}=x^{k-1}-\alpha\nabla F(x^{k-1})$.

Is there any advantage?

Comment: Speed.  It's all about speed.  What you wrote above is steepest descent.  Newton's method requires an inverse.

Comment: You don't need to compute the Jacobian inverse.
$x^{k}=x^{k-1}-J(x^{k-1})^{-1}F(x^{k-1})$
but this expression is equal to 
J(x^{k-1})^{-1}(x^{k}-x^{k-1})=-F(x^{k-1})

Comment: True, you don't need to directly compute the inverse in N-R, but it's clear that the computational cost per iteration is higher, right?

Comment: I'm not sure who keeps downvoting this question.  Perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: What is SGD? ${}$

Comment: Newton's method is a fundamental and extremely popular optimization algorithm. Newton's method requires solving a large linear system of equations at each iteration and for large scale problems the cost of solving that linear system might be prohibitive.

Comment: How accurate a solution do you want?  For machine learning purposes SGD is often good enough even though it doesn't find the minimum very accurately in reasonable time.

Comment: @copper.hat Stochastic gradient descent, I think.

Comment: @Novice Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question is the same as the answer to the question " Why do folks use SGD instead of GD"? I mean the answer is computational cost, assuming all other factors are good

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is Newton's method not widely used in machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/253632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why don't we find the roots of $\nabla F(x)=0$ by means of a numerical method like Newton-Raphson instead of updating with SGD and variants?

Is there such a thing? You could apply any method to compute a minimum. I can say that; usually, it's not needed much precision on the root for a good candidate of minimizer. Other than that, not necessarily, whenever $\|\nabla F (x)\| \leq \epsilon$, $x$ is a good solution, and not necessarily the Hessian, say $\nabla^{2} f$, have good condition number around the solution. For example, the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(0)=0$ and $g(x) = x^2\exp(-1/x^2),$ for all other $x \in \mathbb{R},$ is convex, but the Hessian is terribly behaved. This means that Newton's method does not behave well for that problem. On the other hand, gradient-based methods, due to an Armijo-type rule, might take more significant steps toward the minimum when compared to Newton's method. Also, stochastic gradient descent does not require storing a large matrix as the Hessian and the entire gradient of a function. For example, when a function is a sum of simple convex functions, like in the least-square problem, the SDG needs to compute one gradient of the simple convex functions per iteration, and yet a good solution will be found in a small number of epochs (usually, not more than ten epochs). On the contrary, Newton's method requires computing each of the gradients of the simple convex functions and then sum all, and, after, needs to solve a linear system. Each Newton's method step has at least the cost of one epoch. In summary, if you don't need high precision (or you need "low" precision, like in machine learning to overcome data overfitting) and your objective function is a sum of simple convex functions, SGD is a good algorithm for your problem.